# RegEx for cutting phone number

Tags: regex, phone-number

I just need to find phone number in description and remove it using regular expressions. Phone numbers would be in following formats:

- 998991234567
- +998 99 123 45 67
- 1234567
- 991234567
- (998)901234567

I have found following regex, but do not know what to change:
/^(+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{12}$/

Comment: Do you know what your regex does? Can you formulate regexes for each sample of it's own and have problems combining them or are you stuck at one of these?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example of numbers format, this regex will work

```
/([0-9]{12})|(\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{9})|(\+[0-9]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2})|[^0-9]([0-9]{7})[^0-9]|[^0-9]([0-9]{9})[^0-9]/gm
```

You can use the pip `|` character to set more than one regex format to match.

Also you can test your regex in https://regex101.com/r/fzB1nL/1